# How do you make PC Minecraft look like Xbox?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been playing Minecraft on Xbox for awhile now and am so used to it. When I got the PC version, I noticed that the sensitivity is really high, it's darker and the frame rate is different.

How do I make the PC version similar to the Xbox version in terms of the brightness, the frame rate and the sensitivity?

Comment: Have you tried tweaking with the settings?

Answer (score 2):

You can change everything in the game's settings. (Escape button while in-game > Options)

You can change the sensitivity, the Max Framerate (If you get a higher framerate that you actually want to have, it depends on your PC specs!) and brighter too!

You can even bind your Xbox controller to the game's buttons. I did that and I had tons of fun playing Minecraft with a controller.

Comment: not to mention third party applications that can affect a range of things

Comment: Third Party applications are useless for me if the game has the same settings.

Comment: they don't just do the same things, there are plenty of things you cant accomplish with in game settings. I realize the in game settings are probably what OP is looking for, I was merely suggesting other possibilities that could be useful.

Comment: That is interesting to me, could you tell me what else can I change with those 3rd party programs?

Comment: Colour warmth dependant on time (flux) is one that I use

Comment: I think that can be modified, can't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can have resource pack to change any texture needed for looks. For brightness, you can go to the video setting and experiment a bit.

You can use 3rd party app for controller to hook up with Minecraft. If the sensitivity is too high, you can lower it by going into control settings.

Unfortunately about the frame rate, it depends on your PC specs.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to make it look like you've questioned but the truth is that you need to find out the patches to make Xbox look like PC also you have to look in the internet and try to transfer SD card to patch it to the Xbox so you can somehow make this work for now, also regarding to that, you need to make this possible so you can be able to be better with the PC looking Xbox. The possibility for to get Xbox to look like PC is 23.6% of chance if you had that right.

Comment: The user who asked the question wants the PC version to look like the XBOX version, not the other way around.